# download option is not working when i open my website in opera browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp web form i given a download option to download the image and text which is inside the id:div. it is working when i used the chrome browser but opera and like that browser are not perform the operation. help for in that case.thanks in advance

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Give some reference for that